# Is GoTurn tracker supported in opencv 3.1 python api?

Tags: opencv3.0

I'm trying to create a GOTURN tracker using opencv, but the process finishes with error:

`self.tracker = cv2.Tracker_create("GOTURN")`

Process finished with exit code 139

If I change the type of tracker to MIL, BOOSTING, MEDIANFLOW, TLD or KCF it works well.

It seems the python api doesn't support this kind of tracker yet, is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the master branch of 3.2 version, so Goturn is not included in 3.1 version. Have to wait.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/ddd/tracker_8hpp.html